# Right click event, I need to get actual component that is right clicked as sender instead of ContextMenuItem

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling, arguments

I am applying right click option on a PictureBox to delete that picture from a virtual Folder
tried following code:

```
    main()
    {
        //Some where in main()
        PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
        pb.ContextMenu = contextMenu_pictureBoxRightClick;
    }

    private void menuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Here sender is actual the menuItem which is clicked after right Clicking the picture
        PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)sender;
        // Doing somthing to PictureBox!!! 
    }
```

but receive error casting because sender is actual ContextMenuItem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the actual component (`PictureBox` in this case) that was right-clicked from `ContextMenuItem` this way :

```
var menuItem = (MenuItem)sender;
var ctxMenu = (ContextMenu)menuItem.Parent;
var actualComponent = (PictureBox)ctxMenu.SourceControl;
//or in short
var actualComponent = (PictureBox)((ContextMenu)((MenuItem)o).Parent).SourceControl;
```

Comment: Thanks @har07: This worked

    ToolStripMenuItem mi = (ToolStripMenuItem)sender;
    ContextMenuStrip cms = (ContextMenuStrip)mi.Owner;
    PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)cms.SourceControl;

Answer (score 0):

This code is failing because `sender` represents the object on which the event occured.  In this case it is the menu item and not the `PictureBox`

It sounds like you want to access a `PictureBox` value when a specific menu item is clicked.  If that is the case then the best route is to make the `PictureBox` value a field and access it directly from the click handler

```
PictureBox pb;

main() {
  ...
  pb = new PictureBox();
  pb.ContextMenu = contextMenu_pictureBoxRightClick;
}

private void menuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  // pb can be used directly here 
}
```

Comment: Thanks but solution provided by har07 worked for me. I can't use this solution because my pictureBoxes are added at runtime.